# Rspec test for a helper in my case

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rspec2

I am developing a **Rails** app. I have a helper under *app/helpers/* , that's the
**db_data_helper.rb**.

The methods in this **db_data_helper** are mainly used to execute sql dump file to load data to database.  And these methods in the helper are used in some Rake task.

Some sample code of the helper:

**db_data_helper.rb:**

```
module DbDataHelper

  def self.load_data
       # CODE TO EXECUTE SQL dump files
  end
  ...
  ...
end
```

Now, I would like to **test** this helper in **Rspec** but I am not sure how to implement the test in Rspec for a helper like this. Could some one help me on this?

Comment: Why does your **VIEW**Helper load data into your database? Use `db/seed.rb` if you need to load up data once. Or write a nice DbImporter some where else. (like in /lib or `/app/my_app_name/db_importer.rb`).

Answer (score -1):

I'd simply create a class in my spec file:

```
class DummyDbDataHelper
  extend DbDataHelper
end

describe DummyDbDataHelper do
  it "tests the load_data method" do
    DummyDbDataHelper.load_data.should ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Although this is a correct answer, it is very bad practice to this in a view helper.

Comment: @Ariejan: this seems not to be a view helper

Comment: @Ariejan: did you ever see a custom helper method at the class level?